# flush_rewrite_rules on every register_post_type?

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm stuck in an awful situation and I think it's because I've registered 5 post types but calling flash_rewrite_rules() function just once, so I have this question:

Should I call flash_rewrite_rules() function after each registration of custom post type or just one call?

And by the way, is it OK to have 10 custom post type for a theme (or as many as we want)? any effect on performance?

Thank you.

```
    <?php 

/*** Registering book post type ***/
function px_book() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => 'books',
    'singular_name'      => 'book',
    'menu_name'          => 'books',
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => 5,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields' )
  );

  register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'px_book' );

/*** Registering book post type ***/
function px_movie() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => 'movies',
    'singular_name'      => 'movie',
    'menu_name'          => 'movies',
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'movie' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => 5,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields' )
  );

  register_post_type( 'movie', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'px_movie' );

add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
?>
```

or like this:

```
    <?php 

/*** Registering book post type ***/
function px_book() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => 'books',
    'singular_name'      => 'book',
    'menu_name'          => 'books',
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => 5,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields' )
  );

  register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'px_book' );
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules' );

/*** Registering book post type ***/
function px_movie() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => 'movies',
    'singular_name'      => 'movie',
    'menu_name'          => 'movies',
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'movie' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => 5,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields' )
  );

  register_post_type( 'movie', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'px_movie' );

add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
?>
```

Comment: What is the "awful situation"? What is the problem?

Comment: Wordpress acts weird when using  flash_rewrite_rules() function. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't! I think it's because I'm calling  flash_rewrite_rules() just once. how many time do I have to call this function? On every creation of new custom post type or just once? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, "acts weird" is not actionable debugging information. And there is no code to analyze so it is hard to say what is happening, other that it should be `flush_` not `flash_` and you should only run the function when the CPT is created and not on every page load.

Comment: Some info maybe enlighten the question/problem (flush)[Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules#Usage). And when it is about amount of custom post types... if done well (coded) and used well it is up to you (imho), 10/20 50 name it. But don't overdo, and you maybe look at(change) your goal/strategie. (also just mho)

Comment: Sorry, my post is now more complete. So which is better? Thank you.

Comment: your second example doesn't do what you think it does. `add_action` adds a reference to your function to a queue. your code isn't adding a post type, flushing rules, adding another post type, flushing rules again. it's adding functions to queues to run when those actions are invoked by WordPress, which happens once for each action in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Don't call `flush_rewrite_rules`. It's a super expensive call to make and slows everything down.

Also the order matters, but the correct thing to do is register all your content types, then re-save permalinks in WP Admin, and then... nothing, you've done everything. Only flush permalinks when things have changed, not on every page load. Visiting the permalinks page should be enough to flush them.

Also, don't register post types and taxonomies inside themes, you'll loose access to the data when the user switches to another theme. Themes are for looks, plugins are for functionality

Comment: Agree with everything Tom said here, but with a caveat.  If you are writing a plugin to distribute to other people and that plugin adds rewrite rules directly, or indirectly via post types, taxonomies, etc. you'll still want to use `flush_rewrite_rules()`, but typically only within activation and deactivation hooks.
And to caveat my caveat, what I just wrote here is a rule of thumb, not an absolute. There are other times it makes sense to call `flush_rewrite_rules()`. If you really understand what you are doing then call it. Otherwise, avoid it and just go with Tom's recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are flushing the rewrite rules before the post types are registered. Your `after_switch_theme` should look something like this:

```
function px_book() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => 'books',
    'singular_name'      => 'book',
    'menu_name'          => 'books',
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => 5,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields' )
  );

  register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'px_book' );

function px_movie() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => 'movies',
    'singular_name'      => 'movie',
    'menu_name'          => 'movies',
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'movie' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => 5,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields' )
  );

  register_post_type( 'movie', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'px_movie' );

add_action( 'after_switch_theme', function() {

    // At this point, post types are not registered

    // register post types
    px_movie();
    px_book();

    // flush rewrite rules
    flush_rewrite_rules();

} );
```

Why? When you click on "Activate" a theme, the `init` event in the next page load is triggered before your theme is activated, so on `after_switch_theme` the functions you hook on `init` are not triggered. It is similar what is described in [register_post_type on Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Flushing_Rewrite_on_Activation) when registering post types in plugins (by the way, I think registering post types should be done in plugins, not in themes. Themes are for look and feel, post types are content structure, not look and feel. If you switch to another theme you lose the content, **that is very bad**).

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm aware of registering post types through plugins but in my scenario I want to register new post types through theme and not through plugin and my code is just like codex example about registering post types through themes. So I still don't understand why my code is wrong? Is it really wrong?! It's just like the codex example!

Comment: I've explained to you: on `after_switch_theme` event, the `init` event was already triggered but not your `init` hook because your theme wasn't activated at that moment. Also, I linked to an example on codex where you can what I'm saying and an example similar to the code on the answer and not like your code for registering post types on themes. You just need to call the functions that register the post types inside `after_switch_theme` hook plus on `init`. Please, if my answer fix your problem and answer your question, remember to check it as accepted answer.

Comment: Just to clarify, it is the same approach to register post types and `register_activation_hook` used in plugin. You need to register post types both on `init` and `register_activation_hook` in case you need to flush the rewrite rules. In the case of themes `register_activation_hook` is replaced with `after_switch_theme`.

Comment: @pershianix if cybmeta fixed your problem then please consider accepting his answer so the question can be marked as resolved.